# How associations can be set with non id foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have following migrations:

```
class CreateDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :devices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :abbr

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateVendors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :vendors do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :abbr

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateDeviceVendors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :device_vendors do |t|
      t.string :device
      t.string :vendor

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

There is many to many relationship between device and vendor, so DeviceVendors table is getting used for that. Both tables abbr column (which is unique) is getting saved in this table as device and vendor respectively.

I am using this kind of table structure so that I can seed the data and don't have to check for ids in the primary tables.

How can I set the association in all three models so that I can access in better way. Something like this:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_vendors
  has_many :vendors, through: device_vendors
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_vendors
  has_many :devices, through: device_vendors
end

class DeviceVendor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device
  belongs_to :vendor
end
```

I know I have to apply `foreign_key: :abbr` to belongs_to in models but not sure in which ones. Also whether I need to change/add the migration for this?

Comment: a sorta of side note, you will want to `index uniq: true` the `abbr` columns of `devices` and `vendors`, as well as `index uniq: true` `[:device, :vendor]` and `[:vendor, :device]` on `device_vendors`. to ensure uniqueness and speed up searches

Answer (score 1):

The `foreign_key`, as you point out, is on the `belongs_to` table, but you need to specify both `primary_key` and `foreign_key` (since none is the default `id`) in all associations:

```
class Device < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_vendors, primary_key: "abbr", foreign_key: "device"
  has_many :vendors, through: device_vendors
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :device_vendors, primary_key: "abbr", foreign_key: "vendor"
  has_many :devices, through: device_vendors
end

class DeviceVendor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device, primary_key: "abbr", foreign_key: "device"
  belongs_to :vendor, primary_key: "abbr", foreign_key: "vendor"
end
```

Also notice that the foreign key is not `abbr`, that's the primary key in both `device` and `vendor`; the foreign key is the one in the table with `belongs_to` (i.e. `device` and `vendor` in `device_vendors`).

Comment: This is correct for how to get rails to handle it.  But you should also add the index, primary key, and foreign key flags in the migration to optimize it and prevent race conditions.